# PySFTP/Paramiko exceptions leaking into stderr

Tags: python, exception, paramiko, stderr, pysftp

I am trying to catch `paramiko` exceptions but they are still written to stderr.

Is there a way to stop writing there?

EDIT: It happens even before paramiko gets involved:

```
import pysftp

try:
    pysftp.Connection(host="localhost")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Results in:

[image]

Example with proper SFTP params:

[image]

UPDATE:

```
$ pipenv graph
...
pysftp==0.2.9
  - paramiko [required: >=1.17, installed: 2.6.0]
...

$ pipenv run python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 19 2019, 11:21:39)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.28.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pysftp
>>> try:
...     pysftp.Connection(host="localhost")
... except Exception as e:
...     print(e)
...
No hostkey for host localhost found.
Exception ignored in: <function Connection.__del__ at 0x10f7e8268>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andrei/Work/try/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 1013, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/Users/andrei/Work/try/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 784, in close
    if self._sftp_live:
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute '_sftp_live'
>>>
```

Comment: I'm not getting any output to stderr from Paramiko. We need [mcve].

Comment: Hmm, I got same issue even before Paramiko got involved. However, I think we had this problem with other libs using paramiko. stderr is usually sent to Sentry where each stderr line creates a separate Sentry Issue.

Comment: Does the example work for you now?

Comment: No. I do not get any output to stderr from neither Paramiko nor pysftp. Again, we need [mcve].

Comment: I guess the platform is different or the python version. Can it depend on some env vars?

Comment: I get the same error running the same code as you.

Comment: The problem is that it's expected to just print `No hostkey for host localhost found.` to stdout without any stack trace. Why is it writing to stderr? Is there a logger configured to do it?

Comment: @Andrei: Did any of the answers solve your problem? If yes, could you be so kind to mark it as a solution, so that the whole community can benefit from it? If no, could you please specify what more needs to done to it so that it qualifies as a solution?

Answer (score 4):

I want to start by pointing out that *PySFTP* ([[PyPI]: PySFTP](https://pypi.org/project/pysftp/)) has not been maintain for ***3+*** years (or has been moved to a different location - which so far is kept secret :) ).

I reproduced the problem. Below is a more verbose version of your code.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import pysftp
import traceback


def main(argv):
    hostname = argv[0] if argv else "localhost"
    print("Attempting to connect to {0:s} ...".format(hostname))
    try:
        print("----------Before conn----------")
        conn = pysftp.Connection(host=hostname)
        print("----------After conn----------")
    except:
        print("----------Before exc print----------")
        traceback.print_exc()
        print("----------After exc print----------")
    finally:
        print("----------Finally----------")
    print("----------After try / except / finally----------")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    print("pysftp version: {0:s}\n".format(pysftp.__version__))
    main(sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q058110732]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
> pysftp version: 0.2.9
>
> Attempting to connect to localhost ...
> ----------Before conn----------
> e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py:61: UserWarning: Failed to load HostKeys from C:\Users\cfati\.ssh\known_hosts.  You will need to explicitly load HostKeys (cnopts.hostkeys.load(filename)) or disableHostKey checking (cnopts.hostkeys = None).
>   warnings.warn(wmsg, UserWarning)
> ----------Before exc print----------
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "code00.py", line 13, in main
>     conn = pysftp.Connection(host=hostname)
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
>     self._tconnect['hostkey'] = self._cnopts.get_hostkey(host)
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 71, in get_hostkey
>     raise SSHException("No hostkey for host %s found." % host)
> paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No hostkey for host localhost found.
> ----------After exc print----------
> Exception ignored in: <function Connection.__del__ at 0x000001CC720C80D0>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 1013, in __del__
>     self.close()
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 784, in close
>     if self._sftp_live:
> AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute '_sftp_live'
> ----------Finally----------
> ----------After try / except / finally----------
>
> Done.
> ```

It's a *PySFTP* bug:

1. The *Connection* object is constructed (*__new__*)
2. The initializer (*__init__*) is called

   1. Somewhere in the initializer an exception occurs
   2. The lines after the exception are not executed
3. When the object is (automatically) garbage collected (when it goes out of scope, at the end of the *except* block), in its *close* method (called by the destructor (*__del__*)), some attributes are referenced

   1. But since those attributes initialization occurs **after** the line (raising the exception) from ***#2.2.***, they were never initialized, so their reference raises *AttributeError*

The fix is straightforward: initialize the attributes to some default values, at the initializer's beginning, so their reference doesn't represent a problem if the above scenario happens.

I noticed that you've already submitted an issue on *BitBucket*.

Considering that:

- I'm not a *BitBucket* expert
- I don't have permissions on [[BitBucket]: dundeemt/pysftp - pysftp is an easy to use sftp module that utilizes paramiko and pycrypto.](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src/default) (I can neither push nor submit pull requests)

I created my own *repo* (out of the above one), and pushed the changes at: **[[BitBucket]: CristiFati0/pysftp - [Issue #144]: Exceptions leaking into stderr](https://bitbucket.org/CristiFati0/pysftp/commits/764ee81c17fe3f1c56a9d07f70eef0c686dd3d59)** (one commit, so far).

**Output** (after manually applying the fix to the file installed by *pip*):

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q058110732]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
> pysftp version: 0.2.9
>
> Attempting to connect to localhost ...
> ----------Before conn----------
> e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py:61: UserWarning: Failed to load HostKeys from C:\Users\cfati\.ssh\known_hosts.  You will need to explicitly load HostKeys (cnopts.hostkeys.load(filename)) or disableHostKey checking (cnopts.hostkeys = None).
>   warnings.warn(wmsg, UserWarning)
> ----------Before exc print----------
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "code00.py", line 13, in main
>     conn = pysftp.Connection(host=hostname)
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 135, in __init__
>     self._tconnect['hostkey'] = self._cnopts.get_hostkey(host)
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 71, in get_hostkey
>     raise SSHException("No hostkey for host %s found." % host)
> paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No hostkey for host localhost found.
> ----------After exc print----------
> ----------Finally----------
> ----------After try / except / finally----------
>
> Done.
> ```

Needless to say, other unhandled exceptions might be raised for different scenarios.

### ***@EDIT0***

Apparently, ther's more to this than meets the eye. Besides the ***PySFTP* bug described above**, there are 2 more things that pollute *stderr*.

#### 1. The warning

In my case (as I am on *Win* and don't have any native *SSH* tool installed) it pops up every time (unless I create / copy some valid *known_hosts* file in my home *dir*), but on *Nix* systems it most likely won't.

Anyway, the fix for this one (if wanted) is easy, simply suppress the *UserWarning* for example by setting the ***%PYTHONWARNINGS%*** *env* *var* to ***ignore::UserWarning*** (can also be achieved from code - like in next item's case).

#### 2. *Paramiko* exceptions

I was able to reproduce this by manually modifying *transport.py* (and raising `socket.timeout`).

`paramiko.Transport` which is initialized by `pysftp.Connection._start_transport` (called by the initializer) does its work **in a thread** (by subclassing `threading.Thread`). Any exception raised in that thread, **can't be caught by the *calling* thread** (ours). This is a *Python* limitation scheduled to be addressed in *v**3.8*** ([[Python.Bugs]: threading.Thread should have way to catch an exception thrown within](https://bugs.python.org/issue36666)).

For this one, there is a (lame) workaround (*gainarie*): redirecting *stderr*. Of course there are other workarounds, but they would imply modifying *Paramiko*, so I'd advice against them.

Below is an example that redirects *stderr* to *stdout* (but you can choose any other file - including */dev/null* (or *nul* on *Win*)). It does it from code (but it can also be done from interpreter command line) so that **it only affects the desired (hot) area(s)**.

*code01.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import pysftp
import paramiko
import traceback
import threading


_sys_stderr = sys.stderr  # For restoring purposes


def main(argv):
    hostname = argv[0] if argv else "localhost"
    print("Attempting to connect to {0:s} ...".format(hostname))
    try:
        cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
        cnopts.hostkeys = None
        print("---------- STATS: {0:s} {1:d} ----------".format(__file__, threading.get_ident()))
        print("---------- Before conn ----------")
        sys.stderr.write("DUMMY TEXT before sent to stderr\n")
        sys.stderr = sys.stdout  # @TODO - cfati: decomment so that everything from stderr is redirected to stdout
        conn = pysftp.Connection(host=hostname, port=22001, username="usr", password="pwd", cnopts=cnopts,)
        print("---------- After conn ----------")
    except:
        sys.stderr = _sys_stderr
        print("---------- Before exc tb ----------")
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
        print("---------- After exc tb ----------")
    finally:
        sys.stderr = _sys_stderr
        print("---------- Finally ----------")
        sys.stderr.write("DUMMY TEXT after sent to stderr\n")
    print("---------- After try / except / finally ----------")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    print("pysftp version: {0:s}\nparamiko version: {1:s}".format(pysftp.__version__, paramiko.__version__))
    main(sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q058110732]> sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> code01.py
>
> [prompt]> :: Suppress warning
> [prompt]> set PYTHONWARNINGS=ignore::UserWarning
>
> [prompt]> :: Redirect stdout and stderr to different files, so it is obvious which is which
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code01.py 1>1.out 2>1.err
>
> [prompt]> type 1.err
> DUMMY TEXT before sent to stderr
> DUMMY TEXT after sent to stderr
>
> [prompt]> type 1.out
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
> pysftp version: 0.2.9
> paramiko version: 2.6.0
> Attempting to connect to localhost ...
> ---------- STATS: code01.py 23016 ----------
> ---------- Before conn ----------
> ---------- STATS: e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py 45616 ----------
> Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2212, in _check_banner
>     raise socket.timeout()
> socket.timeout
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2039, in run
>     self._check_banner()
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2218, in _check_banner
>     "Error reading SSH protocol banner" + str(e)
> paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
>
> ---------- Before exc tb ----------
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2212, in _check_banner
>     raise socket.timeout()
> socket.timeout
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "code01.py", line 23, in main
>     conn = pysftp.Connection(host=hostname, port=22001, username="usr", password="pwd", cnopts=cnopts,)
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 144, in __init__
>     self._transport.connect(**self._tconnect)
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1291, in connect
>     self.start_client()
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 660, in start_client
>     raise e
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2039, in run
>     self._check_banner()
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2218, in _check_banner
>     "Error reading SSH protocol banner" + str(e)
> paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
> ---------- After exc tb ----------
> ---------- Finally ----------
> ---------- After try / except / finally ----------
>
> Done.
> ```

And how it looks from *PyCharm* (had to stretch it to the max to fit the whole thing):

[image: img0]

Comment: Nice! They have an open issue about `_sftp_live` so if you make a PR they may like it. However, I am mostly wondering how do the exception(s) leak into stderr. It's happening for other reasons as well and this was just an example. My main issue is that Sentry gets spammed by stderr lines when it happens in production.

Comment: I don't know (so far) how to create a *PR* to their repo (that's why I tried on mine, but I can't figure out how to transfer my changes back to their repo). The error text goes to *stderr* because some operations that happen implicitly (without being in your code). That is the object destruction. The object was created in the *try* block, and partially initialized (but still **it was created** even if it's not accessible from code). Since it was created it must be destroyed too, to avoid memory leaks. The destruction triggers the exception.

Comment: Hmm, what about the paramiko exception? Why is it also written to stderr?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce it. Could you update the question providing some more details on how to run into it?

Comment: I believe it's kinda self-explaining if you look at the trace though. You need to get a socket timeout for your SSH or SFTP connection. I think the easiest to do is to modify the paramiko code in site-packages to trigger the exception for any connection.

Comment: Without a mean to reproduce the error, I can only assume. I assume that smth similar is happening in *paramiko*'s case. But again, please provide a clear way to reproduce that error, in order for me to be able to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200133/discussion-between-cristifati-and-andrei).

Comment: No I didn't, but I don't think that messing around with my files is the way to go. I am not sure when this error occurs, at what point, what's the code that triggered it. BTW, do you still encounter after applying the fix? It seems like a different error though. How did you get it? Can you run the code I posted and paste the output with the error?

Comment: Patching stderr is not something I want to do, but it was useful to know it happens in a thread.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the only way, considering the current setup (*Python* and other tools). If you wait for *v3.8*, or don't use *Paramiko* (or *PySFTP* as pointed out by @delica) there are (might be) others, but they are kind of outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would skip pysftp and just use paramiko as it support SFTP just fine by itself:

```
import paramiko

host,port = "example.com",22
transport = paramiko.Transport((host,port))
username,password = "bar","foo"
transport.connect(None,username,password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
```

Then here you can again try to catch the exception at exactly where it occurs and see how you fare.

Or if you need to authenticate with only password:

```
client = pk.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(pk.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=ip, port=22, username=userName, password=pwd)
ftp_client = client.open_sftp()
```