# throw exit code 0xC0000005 when using easyhook in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, easyhook

i am trying to work on easyhook in python and here is my code

```py
# Hook/EasyHook.py
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.util import find_library
from pathlib import Path

c_ulong_p = POINTER(c_ulong)
c_void_pp=POINTER(c_void_p)

res_path = str(Path(__file__).parent / 'res' / 'EasyHook64.dll')
lib_path = find_library(res_path)
clib = cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path)


class TRACED_HOOK_HANDLE(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Link", c_void_p)]


lh_install_hook = clib.LhInstallHook
lh_install_hook.restype = c_ulong
lh_install_hook.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p, c_void_p, TRACED_HOOK_HANDLE]

# some definition of other functions...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from ctypes.wintypes import *

    t_dll = CDLL('User32.dll')
    test=lambda:t_dll.MessageBoxW(None, 'hi content!', 'hi title!', 0)
    test()

    interface=CFUNCTYPE(c_int, HWND, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, UINT)

    def fake_function(handle, title, message, flag):
        return t_original(handle, "hooked "+title, "hooked "+message, flag)


    t_hook_info = TRACED_HOOK_HANDLE(None)
    if lh_install_hook(t_dll.MessageBoxW, interface(fake_function), None, byref(t_hook_info)):
        raise Exception("Hook error[%s]:\n%s" % (rtl_get_last_error(), rtl_get_last_error_string()))
    # error occur here and the program terminate
    # some other tests...
```

after a try, it exit on code 0xC0000005 when running to `lh_install_hook` calling and without any exception printed

then I tried to use those Api after inject into a C++ program by

```
lh_install_hook(func_address, interface(hook_function), None, byref(hook_info))
```

where `func_address` is the actual address of target call,and it cause

```
python38.dll+24174
_ctypes.pyd+A48D
python38.dll+33E00
python38.dll+3DA6E
_ctypes.pyd+3C69
_ctypes.pyd+38AB
python38.dll+507F5
python38.dll+491C8
```

is there any way to make it run?

Edit:
here is my code inject and run in the c++ programe

```py
# Hook/__init__.py
from .EasyHook import *


class Hook(object):
    def __init__(self, func_address: int):
        self.enabled = False
        self.hook_info = TRACED_HOOK_HANDLE(None)
        self._ACLEntries = (c_ulong * 1)(0)
        self.ACLEntries = cast(self._ACLEntries, POINTER(c_ulong))
        interface = CFUNCTYPE(self.restype, *self.argtypes)

        def hook_function(*args):
            return self.hook_function(*args)

        if lh_install_hook(func_address, interface(hook_function), None, byref(self.hook_info)):
            raise LocalHookError()
        # error occur here and the program terminate
        # some other codes...

    restype = c_void_p
    argtypes = []

    def hook_function(self, *args):
        return self.original(*args)
```

```py
# main.py
from Hook import Hook
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

class kernel32_beep_hook(Hook):
    restype = c_bool
    argtypes = [DWORD,DWORD]

    def hook_function(self, a1, a2):
        if logger is not None:
            logger.log('beep_hook','%s,%s'%(a1,a2))
        return self.original(a1,a2)

# some skip codes
addr=kernel32.GetProcAddress(kernel32_module,b"Beep")
ctypes.windll.kernel32.Beep(500,500)
hook=kernel32_beep_hook(addr)
# error occur here and the program terminate
```

Comment: I don't know if you have any interface definition errors, but one thing to watch out for is in `lh_install_hook(func_address, interface(hook_function), None, byref(hook_info))`.  `interface(hook_function)` has to exist for the lifetime that `hook_function` may be called, but it goes out of scope right after `lh_install_hook` is called.  Store it in a variable to maintain a reference.

Comment: @MarkTolonen thanks for comment, I think this wont be the current problem, the program is terminate before "install", I try to look at the memory page by cheat engine and find that the memory where the function is havn't change when it terminate.

Comment: `hook_f = interface(fake_function)
lh_install_hook(t_dll.MessageBoxW, hook_f, None, byref(t_hook_info))`# this ok
 
`lh_install_hook(t_dll.MessageBoxW, interface(fake_function), None, byref(t_hook_info)) ` #  not work,  why?

Comment: @CSQGB it is because the gc system in python, which when a piece of memory is not be used by function (or store by a PYTHON variable), it will be free, so when the hooked function is call, it try to access a freed/another used memory as a function]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [[GitHub]: EasyHook/EasyHook - (master) EasyHook/Public/easyhook.h](https://github.com/EasyHook/EasyHook/blob/master/Public/easyhook.h):

```c
typedef struct _HOOK_TRACE_INFO_
{
    PLOCAL_HOOK_INFO        Link;
}HOOK_TRACE_INFO, *TRACED_HOOK_HANDLE;
```

*TRACED_HOOK_HANDLE* **is actually a pointer** (although its name suggests the opposite), therefore your *lh_install_hook.argtypes* (1<sup>st</sup> snippet) is incorrect. It should be:

```py
lh_install_hook.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p, c_void_p, POINTER(TRACED_HOOK_HANDLE)]
```

Technically, you ran into [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011).

Regarding no exception being thrown, maybe [[SO]: Python exception thrown by libtidy is amusingly impossible to catch (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59054833/python-exception-thrown-by-libtidy-is-amusingly-impossible-to-catch/59071499#59071499) should shed some light.

This should get past the problem, at least the main one. I'm not sure whether there are others, as I didn't install (or build) the *.lib*, so I didn't run your code. 
My knowledge is very limited (so this might be complete nonsense), but one potential spot to generate problems is *TRACED_HOOK_HANDLE->Link* being initialized to *NULL*.

Comment: Very thanks for your answer! although there are still some coding mistake other than what you point out in my code, but you help me to find out the biggest mistake :)

Comment: You're welcome! It's better to handle each (major) mistake in a separate question to make it easier for whoever runs into one of them.

Comment: @nyao can you show me the fixed code. I meet the same problem

Comment: @CSQGB i put an example code in my github https://github.com/nyaoouo/PyEzH/