# Avoiding undefined behavior when an exception occurs in a Python ctypes callback?

Tags: python, callback, ctypes

This C shared library `test.so` defines `cfunc()`, which accepts a callback function:

```
int cfunc(int (*callback)(void)) {
  return callback();
}
```

This Python code calls `cfunc()` using the Python function `callback()`:

```
from ctypes import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./test.so')

@CFUNCTYPE(c_int)
def callback():
  raise RuntimeError

print(lib.cfunc(callback))
```

Because `callback()` raises an exception, it never returns a value.  I believe this causes `ctypes` to trigger undefined behavior, although I haven't dug through the source to know for sure.  At the very least, the value returned by `cfunc()` appears to suggest it is uninitialized.

Is there any way to avoid this undefined behavior?

Wrapping the nominal body of `callback()` in a `try` clause leaves the possibility of an exception in an `except` clause.

I could pass an `int *` to `callback()` and use the referenced `int` to signal whether an exception was raised.  However, I think undefined behavior still occurs in code outside my control.

Is there a way to get the `ctypes` `CFunctionType` object to initialize the return value?  The `ctypes` documentation doesn't seem to mention anything.

Comment: Just as a note: encountered the same in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59054833/python-exception-thrown-by-libtidy-is-amusingly-impossible-to-catch/59071499#59071499.

Comment: That looks frustrating. The callback is an internal implementation detail of `libtidy`?

Comment: Yes it is (was). But the error popped up only in special cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple possibilities, one would be to wrap the pure-python function into a `try..except` and only then jit the C-function with `ctypes`:

```py
import ctypes
def SafeCFunctype(py_fun):
    @ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int)
    def safe():
        try:
            return py_fun()
        except:
            print("Exception!")
            return -1
    return safe
```

For simplicity I've chosen to return `-1` and to log to stdout, in case an error happens, but there are also other options to signal an error.

And now:

```py
@SafeCFunctype
def callback1():
    raise RuntimeError()
    
callback1() # results in
# Exception!
# -1
```

However, the code of `py_fun` is not the only place where the error can happen - an exception is also possible in the glue code, when an python object is converted to a c-int, e.g.:

```py
@SafeCFunctype
def callback2():
    return None

callback2()
# Exception ignored in: <function SafeCFunctype.<locals>.safe at 0x7f31f41dd840>
# -97323988
```

To ensure, that the conversion will work (or the exception happens inside of `try..catch` we can do the following:

```
import ctypes
def SafeCFunctype(py_fun):
    @ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int)
    def safe():
        try:
            # throws if conversion not possible:
            return ctypes.c_int(py_fun())
        except:
            print("Exception!")
            return -1
    return safe
```

now the conversion (and possible exception) happens inside of `ctypes.c_int(py_fun())` and we can be sure, that nothing will go wrong in the boilerplate code inside the created CFunction:

```py
@SafeCFunctype
def callback2():
    return None
    
callback2() # results in
# Exception!
# -1
```

i.e. no random result.

---

For simple code like `return -1` we can be quite sure, that no further exception will be raised `except` clause.

I don't see any way to detect, whether a python-exception was raised in the wrapped callback, because `ctypes` would detect that an exception was raised, print a warning and then clear the error.

Here is an illustration of the above: I use `ffi` to jit a C-wrapper, which would call the `callback` provided by the `ctypes` and check for Python-errors:

```py
import cffi

code_template = r"""
int safe_call(void){{
   typedef int (*functor)(void);
   // this is awfull, but that is how it works:
   functor fun = *((functor *){callback_addressof});
   int res = fun();
   if(PyErr_Occurred()){{
      PyErr_Clear();
      printf("Error detected\n");
      return -1;
   }}
   else{{
      printf("No error detected\n");
      return res;
   }}
}}
"""

def create_safe_functor(functor):
    ffibuilder = cffi.FFI()
    ffibuilder.cdef("int safe_call(void);", override=True)
    code = code_template.format(callback_addressof=ctypes.addressof(functor))
    print(code)
    built_module=ffibuilder.verify(source=code)
    safe_functor = built_module.safe_call
    return safe_functor
```

and now

```py
fun = create_safe_functor(callback)
fun()
# RuntimeError:
# No error detected
# -234235
```

that means the C function is no longer able to detect, that an error accured.

Comment: This is mostly what I meant by wrapping the nominal body of the callback, and it's still vulnerable to exceptions in the `except` clause.  Unfortunately, useful `except` clauses tend to be complicated enough that I think it's not unreasonable to expect an exception occasionally.  Good point about other exceptions in `ctypes` glue code.

Comment: @ov2k As you have the except-clause under control, you can ensure that nothing bad happens independent of which function is passed to decorator. E.g. `return -1` is not going to raise anything. I have added some info, that you cannot detect whether a python error happened or not, once ctypes-wrapper was called.

Comment: Catching exceptions is probably the best workaround we have, but it's still awkward. An `except` clause that's simple enough to avoid exceptions can't do too much (e.g., no I/O). We're glossing over what to do with things like `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt`. Returning the caught exception so that it can be re-raised is messy as well. This is less directed at your answer and more a note for future reference. As a final note, I'm going to use a function that takes `CFUNCTYPE` arguments and outputs the prototype and a decorator. I find that a little more general-purpose.